# In table view cell data was not loading in screen during it's launch?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In this i am having three sections in a table view in which first section will have addresses and radio buttons if i click on radio button it will active and the particular address will be posting depending on the address selection the third section needs to call the api and load the data in the second table view which is present in third section here the problem is during loading for first time when app launched in simulator it is not loading the third section cell data can any one help me how to reduce the error ?

here is the code for table view class

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
         if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false) {
            return 3
        }else {
            return 2
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
    {
        if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false) {
            if (section == 0) {
                return "SHIPPING ADDRESS"
            }
            else if (section == 2) {
                return "SHIPPING METHOD"
            }
            else  {
                return ""
            }
        }
        else {
                if (section == 0) {
                return "SHIPPING ADDRESS"
                }
                else{
                    return ""
                }
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        if (section == 0)
        {
            return shippingArray.count
        }
        else
        {
            return 1
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        if ((addressSelected == true || checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true) && selected == false){
            if (indexPath.section == 0){
                return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            }
            else if (indexPath.section == 1){
                return 62
            }
            else {
                print(height)
                return CGFloat(height)
            }

        }
        else{
            if (indexPath.section == 0){
                return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            }
            else if (indexPath.section == 1){
                return 62
            }
            else {
                return 0
            }

        }
    }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddressTableViewCell
        tableDetails.isHidden = false
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        let arr = shippingArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.nameLabel.text = arr["name"] as? String
        cell.addressLabel.text = arr["address"]as? String
        let mobilenumber : Any =  arr["number"] as AnyObject
        cell.mobileNumberLabel.text = "\(mobilenumber)"
        cell.radioButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.editButton.isHidden = true
        cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
        cell.radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectRadioButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let checkIndex = self.checkIsRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
        if(checkIndex != nil){
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
            cell.editButton.isHidden = false
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
        }
        else
        {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
            cell.editButton.isHidden = true
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = true
        }
        if (checkIsPaymentRadioSelect == true){
        let defaultvalue  = arr["default"] as! Int
        if defaultvalue == 1 {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
            cell.editButton.isHidden = false
            cell.deleteButton.isHidden = false
            addressSelected = true
            tableDetails.tableFooterView?.isHidden = false
        }
        }
        return cell
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addresscell", for: indexPath) as! CreateNewAddressTableViewCell
        cell.newAddressButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newAddressAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingmethodcell", for: indexPath) as! MethodTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.boolDelegate = self
        cell.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        if shippingRadio == true {
            cell.select = shippingRadio
            cell.boolSelected()
            cell.shippingmethodURL()
            cell.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        }
        else{
            cell.select = methodRadio
            cell.shippingTableView.reloadData()
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

in this cell class i had got the api data and is passed to table view as shown in the code now i need to call api during cell selection of address can anyone help me how to clear the error or any alternative for this

```
var chekIndex:IndexPath?
    var arrayss =  [String:Any]()
    var keys = [String]()
    let urlString = "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bVgbyVQGmq?indent=2"
    var delegate: CheckoutDelegate?
    var heightConstant: Int?
    var name = [String]()
    var totalCount = 0
    var radioSelected:Bool?
    var radioSelection: Bool?
    var boolDelegate: BoolValidationDelegate?
    var select:Bool?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        radioSelection = false
        self.shippingmethodURL()
        shippingTableView.delegate = self
        shippingTableView.dataSource = self
        shippingTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        shippingTableView.estimatedRowHeight = shippingTableView.rowHeight
        // Initialization code
    }
    func paymentRadioAction(button : KGRadioButton) {
        _ = button.center
        let centralPoint = button.superview?.convert(button.center, to:self.shippingTableView)
        let indexPath =  self.shippingTableView.indexPathForRow(at: centralPoint!)
        if button.isSelected {

        } else{
            chekIndex = indexPath
            radioSelection = true
            self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
            self.boolDelegate?.boolvalidation(bool: radioSelection!)
        }
    }
    func shippingmethodURL() {
        guard let url = URL(string: self.urlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let data = data, let jsonObj = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String:Any] {
                self.arrayss = jsonObj
                self.keys = Array(jsonObj.keys)
                for value in jsonObj.values {
                    if let array = value as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for element in array {
                            if (element["name"] as? String) != nil {
                                self.totalCount += 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
                    let sectionHeight = self.arrayss.count * 31
                    let cellHeight = self.totalCount * 44
                    self.shippingHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(sectionHeight + cellHeight)
                    self.heightConstant = Int(self.shippingHeightConstraint.constant)
                    self.delegate?.heightConstant(int: self.heightConstant!)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrayss.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.keys[section]
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let key = self.keys[section]
        let a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
        return a.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingCell", for: indexPath) as! ShippingMethodTableViewCell
        let key = self.keys[indexPath.section]
        var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
        var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
        let name = dictionary["name"]
        let price = dictionary ["price"]
        cell.methodLabel.text = name  as? String
        cell.priceLabel.text = price as? String
        cell.radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(paymentRadioAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        if chekIndex == indexPath {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
        } else {
            cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
        }
    return cell
    }
```

and the first time image loading is shown below

[!enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cQLG.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cQLG.png)

and if i select another radio button in first section it was working fine as expected and image is shown below

[image]

Comment: In the number of sections , does the condition get satisfied when the view loads for the first time? Also check the height you are setting for the rows in section.

Comment: got bro height was getting zero for first time so it was not showing thanks for response @AnkitJ